# Mousehover in FilteredTree works outside arrows. How to fix this?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I disabled scaling in my app: `System.setProperty("swt.autoScale", "false");`

Now in a tree the center of mousehover area over tree arrows is shifted to the right. I can expand/collapse tree nodes when clicking apart the arrows (a bit to the right side). See pic1.

If I set bigger font size in tree, I can click on any arrow and expand/collapse works, but still the center of mousehover area is shifted to the right, pic2.

Creating tree:

```java
filterComposite = new TreeFilteredChecked(sashFormTree, SWT.MULTI, filter, this);
```

then:

```java
  public class TreeFilteredChecked extends FilteredTree implements CheckListener{

  private Viewer viewer;
  private List<TreeDataItem> unchecked;
  private String previousText;
  private List<TreeDataItem> toBeChecked = new ArrayList<TreeDataItem>();
  private boolean refreshingScene;
  private Composite treeViewerComposite;

  public TreeFilteredChecked(Composite parent, int treeStyle, PatternFilter filter, Viewer viewer) {
    super(parent, false);
    this.viewer = viewer;
    init(treeStyle, filter);
    unchecked = new ArrayList<TreeDataItem>();
    previousText = "";
    refreshingScene = false;
    
    filterText.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
      // code
    });
    
    ApplicationSizeManager.setFontForControl(filterText, parent.getDisplay());

    ((TreeCheckedViewer)treeViewer).addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
      // code
    });
  }
    
  @Override
  protected TreeViewer doCreateTreeViewer(Composite parent, int style) {
    treeViewerComposite = parent;
    return new TreeCheckedViewer(parent, style, viewer, this);
  }

  // code
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

pic1:

[image: pic1]

pic2:

[image: pic2]

Comment: If you can come up with a [mre] just using SWT rather than SWT/JFace/Eclipse UI that you have here you might be able to ask on the SWT Github https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt I can't reproduce this with a quick test with a checkbox `Tree` on macOS  so it might be specific to your OS.